# position:fixed element inside another position:fixed element doesn't show up (iPad only)

Tags: css, ipad, mobile-safari, css-position

Here is a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hw5Zu/

In short, I have a position:fixed element `.fixedblock` with overflow-y: auto so that overflowing content causes a vertical scrollbar.

*Inside that* I have another position:fixed element `.insideblock`, positioned *outside* the perimeters of .fixedblock. (It's supposed to be the titlebar above the scrolling pane.)

In all the browsers I've tested (latest Chrome, Firefox, IE7-10), `.fixedblock` is visible. It is invisible (cropped) only on Mobile Safari (iPad). (JSFiddle on iPad doesn't show the problem though.)

Which browsers are doing the right thing? Can anyone suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by giving `.fixedblock` a top margin equal to the height of `.insideblock`, and putting `.insideblock` also at top:0, on top the margin. I can't use padding as that makes `.fixedblock`'s scrollbar disappear underneath `.insideblock`. By using margin the scrollbar starts below the margin.

This still has the same problem on the iPad where `.insideblock` is seen as outside the perimeters of `.fixedblock`, and disappears. So I resort to user agent detection and -- for iPad only -- I change the top margin to top padding. This is OK on iPad as it doesn't have scrollbars.